# ActiveRecord query with includes and conditions not giving expected SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Ok, so here's the issue I'm having. I have a model that has two relationships set on conditions in a through table.

```
has_one :link_resource, through: :resource_contexts, source: :resource, conditions: ['resource_contexts.question_id = ? ', -1]
has_many :sample_plans, through: :resource_contexts, source: :resource, conditions: ['resource_contexts.question_id = ? ', -2]
```

Then, in my controller I'm trying to get these included using

```
@funder_templates = FunderTemplate.find(:all, include: [:sample_plans, :link_resource], conditions: {active: true})
```

But for some reason, the sql comes out like this

```
ResourceContext Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `resource_contexts`.* FROM `resource_contexts` WHERE (`resource_contexts`.funder_template_id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,30,40) AND (resource_contexts.question_id = -2 ))
```

Notice it's only looking for the conditions of the first relationship, but not the second. I don't know if what I'm doing is just too complex for ActiveRecord to handle or if I'm just writing it incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Rails 3.0.20

Ruby 1.9.2

Edit: To clarify, the really messed up part is @funder_templates.sample_plans is correct but @funder_templates.link_resource is sample plans as well! Without the includes, the relationships work fine, it's just not optimized.

Comment: You write `include: [:sample_plans, :link_resource]` - these are both relationships.

Comment: @Mik_Die Isn't that what I have written?

Comment: If you wanna try using the more recent syntax... `@funder_templates = FunderTemplate.all.includes([:sample_plans, :link_resource]).where(:active => true)`

Comment: @depa I've tried funder_templates = FunderTemplate.includes([:link_resource, :sample_plans]).where(active: true) but the same issue happens. Both funder_templates.sample_plans and funder_templates.link_resource are both sample_plans. It just doesn't get the second includes relationship for some reason.

Comment: Do you have a `has_many :resource_contexts` line as well? You should.

Comment: @depa Yes, I have a has_many :resource_contexts and had a has_many :resources, through: :resource_contexts. Although, I realized I don't ever use resources without the conditions (thus the aliased conditional relationships) so I took out the has_many :resources line. But the has_many :resource_contexts is still there.

Comment: Do you really need to specify the conditions in the association like that? Can't you just have a single association and then use scopes or instance methods to filter?

Comment: @cyle The issue is resources weren't actually used this way before recently. This app is getting sunsetted soon so it doens't really matter either way, this definitely isn't the cleanest solution, but it allows me to use the existing tables the way I need. I could definitely do it another way, and might end up doing that, but I'm still curious as to what's wrong with my current way. I don't understand why ActiveRecord is behaving the way it is. Is it a bug or am I really writing it wrong? Because I can't tell. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @JoshEmory I'm attempting to reproduce your error and I received an explicit error. My rails version is 3.2.8, and the error message is: `Cannot have a has_one :through association 'FunderTemplate#link_resource' where the :through association 'FunderTemplate#resource_contexts' is a collection. Specify a has_one or belongs_to association in the :through option instead.` I wonder if this is why you're only seeing sample_plans and not link_resource; maybe older versions of rails did not explicitly fail in your scenario (I'm just pontificating here, can't say that for certain).

Comment: @teeg Thanks for that, I'm not at work and don't have my repo on my home computer so I can't try it till tomorrow morning but I'll upgrade the rails and see if it fails. It's possible I don't have all the necessary information in this post. I'll let you know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ? @funder_templates = FunderTemplate.where(active: true).includes([:sample_plans, :link_resource])

I think, it should work

Comment: You probably didn't see my comment to depa but I did try `@funder_templates = FunderTemplate.includes([:link_resource, :sample_plans]).where(active: true)`. Which produced the same results, when I would look at @funder_templates.link_resource and @funder_templates.sample_plans they would both be the sample plans. I ended up going a different route (which similar efficiency), because I believe this is a bug in active record. Possibly in the version we're using in production (3.0.20).